# How do I extract specific data that varies in value from a file in Python

Tags: python, parsing

So I have a file that imports large amounts of data from a vision system. It saves the data in a text file and there are about 4000 lines of text with 1 line per result. I will add 1 of these lines below as an example.

****11/02/1970; 11:56:44.000;ID;002914;Light Check;254;Tube Width1;38.7;Tube Width2;39.2;Tube Width3;39.9;Tube Width4;40.9;Tube Width5;41.2;Fixt Row;175.20;Fixt Col;211.23;Post Width;0.00;Blob Size;0;Left Angle;0.00;Right Angle;17.90;Dark Blob;0;Result;0;Global St;14;Tool Flag;31;Pallet No; 108;****

So what I want to do is be able to do is extract for each line one of the parameters along with its value. There is a delimiter of ; between every space which is making it difficult for me.

So if I for example wanted to choose Light Check, I would get the results of Light Check for each line which in this case is 254. Can someone suggest some functions I could use that could possibly help me with this?

Comment: Is it possible to use `Pandas` to solve your problem?

Comment: I never knew that, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using regular expression (`re` module here), let `file.txt` content be

```
11/02/1970; 11:56:44.000;ID;002914;Light Check;254;Tube Width1;38.7;Tube Width2;39.2;Tube Width3;39.9;Tube Width4;40.9;Tube Width5;41.2;Fixt Row;175.20;Fixt Col;211.23;Post Width;0.00;Blob Size;0;Left Angle;0.00;Right Angle;17.90;Dark Blob;0;Result;0;Global St;14;Tool Flag;31;Pallet No; 108;
```

then

```
import re
with open("file.txt","r") as f:
    for line in f:
        print(re.search(r"Light Check;([0-9]+)",line).group(1))
```

output

```
254
```

Explanation: I iterate over following lines (`for line in f`, thus there is no need to load whole file into memory), then in each line I find 1 or more (`+`) digits (`[0-9]`) after `Light Check;`. Note digits are inside `(` and `)` that is capturing group (first and only) which I access using `group(1)`. Disclaimer: this solution assumes `Light Check;` followed by 1 or more digits is present in each line of `file.txt`.

Comment: That works really well thank you. Just an additional question. Is it possible to use this regular expression but instead of taking just light check it will take an input and extract the data based on the parameter I have entered? So if I type in Light Check I get light check results.

Comment: @KieranF yes, just make sure you feed user input first into [`re.escape`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.escape) before using it as part of pattern to prevent unexcepted behavior if it does contain character of special meaning and replace `[0-9]` using `[.0-9]` if you need to support float values.

Comment: Okay, so I am quite new to this and regular expressions are quite advanced for me. This is what I have tried.                                                                                         
  import re
with open("file.txt","r") as f:
    for line in f:
        s = input("Enter Parameter:")
        re.escape(s)
        print(re.search(s, r"([0-9]+)",line).group(1)) @Daweo

Comment: @KieranF are you sure you want to ask user again for each line? If not `input` should be outside `for` loop, you need to concatenate to get single `str` to use as pattern, try `print(re.search(re.escape(s) + r"([0-9]+)",line).group(1))` (note that this does assume that `;` will be part of user input)

Comment: Okay wow that's much better. I put the input outside the for loop. Thanks for all your help, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

to split that line into a dictionary I would do:

```
s = "11/02/1970; 11:56:44.000;ID;002914;Light Check;254;Tube Width1;38.7;Tube Width2;39.2;Tube Width3;39.9;Tube Width4;40.9;Tube Width5;41.2;Fixt Row;175.20;Fixt Col;211.23;Post Width;0.00;Blob Size;0;Left Angle;0.00;Right Angle;17.90;Dark Blob;0;Result;0;Global St;14;Tool Flag;31;Pallet No; 108;"

s = s.split(";")
data = {key: val for key, val in zip(s[::2], s[1::2])}
```

Which returns

```
data
{'11/02/1970': ' 11:56:44.000', 'ID': '002914', 'Light Check': '254', 'Tube Width1': '38.7', 'Tube Width2': '39.2', 'Tube Width3': '39.9', 'Tube Width4': '40.9', 'Tube Width5': '41.2', 'Fixt Row': '175.20', 'Fixt Col': '211.23', 'Post Width': '0.00', 'Blob Size': '0', 'Left Angle': '0.00', 'Right Angle': '17.90', 'Dark Blob': '0', 'Result': '0', 'Global St': '14', 'Tool Flag': '31', 'Pallet No': ' 108'}
```

You can then do

```
data['Light Check']
```

to get

```
'254'
```

Comment: Thats exactly what I was looking for, thank you. I will give that a try.

Answer (score 1):

Convert your data structure into a list of dict:

```
import csv
from datetime import datetime

with open('data.txt') as fp:
    reader = csv.reader(fp, delimiter=';')
    data = []
    for row in reader:
        row = row[:-1]
        d = {'dt': datetime.strptime(row[0] + row[1], '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S.%f'),
             'id': row[3]}

        keys = row[4::2]
        vals = map(float, row[5::2])
        d.update(dict(zip(keys, vals)))
        data.append(d)
```

Output:

```
>>> data
[{'dt': datetime.datetime(1970, 2, 11, 11, 56, 44),
  'id': '002914',
  'Light Check': 254.0,
  'Tube Width1': 38.7,
  'Tube Width2': 39.2,
  'Tube Width3': 39.9,
  'Tube Width4': 40.9,
  'Tube Width5': 41.2,
  'Fixt Row': 175.2,
  'Fixt Col': 211.23,
  'Post Width': 0.0,
  'Blob Size': 0.0,
  'Left Angle': 0.0,
  'Right Angle': 17.9,
  'Dark Blob': 0.0,
  'Result': 0.0,
  'Global St': 14.0,
  'Tool Flag': 31.0,
  'Pallet No': 108.0}]
```

Search with Python:

```
out = [rec for rec in data if rec.get('Light Check') == 254]
```

Search with Pandas:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
out = df[df['Light Check'] == 254]
```